# How to change the full capitals font title of my WordPress Blog?

Tags: css, title

I would like to show my WordPress blog's title as "Dummit foote 4.2.4". But I am getting all capitals as "DUMMIT FOOTE 4.2.4"

What should I do to change this?

I do not see any editor case in my dashboard.

[image]

It was mentioned that i should change something in .css but i do not even know where to find that.

Answer (score 2):

It is in your stylesheet

```
.entry-title {
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.0909090909;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

You need to remove text-transform: uppercase;

Comment: I am brand new to wordpress.. I can not see stylesheet any where.. :O

Comment: I think you can find it in wp-admin > Appearance > Editor.

Comment: I do not see any editor case here.. I would edit my post showing my window..

Comment: Sorry, I dont know then, didnt realise it was a .com wordpres. You can try asking in their forums for help ?

Comment: If this is wordpress.com hosted site, then you should ask it on their forum.

Comment: WPSE is only for self hosted sites, not wordpress.com

Comment: @PieterGoosen :I have no idea if this is to be here or not.. I have posted this question somewhere and it got migrated here without my involvement...

Comment: Your question got migrated to here, tell me, is your site self hosted or hosted by wordpress.com

Comment: @PieterGoosen it is hosted by wordpress.com... that is the reason i have added the tag wordpress.com :O

Comment: Then your question should be asked on the wordpress.com forum.  And CSS is off topic here as well. Sorry about that

Comment: @PieterGoosen : It may be off topic but can you help me in this case...I would be so thankful to you in that case...

Answer (score 2):

(This answer refers specifically to the theme "twenty seventeen" but should apply in general.)

In order to avoid capitalized letters in site title proceed as follows:

Under design/customizer select the css entry field and enter the following code:

```
.site-title {
    text-transform: none;
}
```

To find out more settings that can be customized, look under design/editor and select the file "Stylesheet (style.css)". In there, use the search function (CTRL + F) to find "site-title". Learn which settings are preset by the selected theme.

Note: AFAIK it is not recommended to change the style.css itself, since it the overwritten by theme updates. Moreover, wordpress developers suggest to use the css entry field mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for this, as I didn't like the CSS solution, and I also wanted exceptions... Check it out.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-titles-case/
and
https://properprogramming.com/tools/wp-change-titles-case/

Comment: But that won't solve the case in the question where the theme is already applying capitals using CSS and it needs to be overridden or removed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).